# Serial Number (Record Count) in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Could some one point out how to include a **Serial Number** while populating from a table on a Razor page view.

Here's my view

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            ---- ??? HOW TO INCLUDE SERIAL NUMBER HERE ??? ----
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.studentName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.studentID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.studentID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.studentID })
        </td>
    </tr>
```

}

*(Im using EF 4.1 scaffolding to autogenerate the contexts and models)*

Comment: Do you have a column on your database which holds the serial number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@item.Serial
```

If you don't want to show it in an html control. You don't need to do anything special.

EDIT: It seems you just want a counter
change the loop in your code to

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.Index
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.studentName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Data.studentID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Data.studentID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Data.studentID })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Comment: CS0103: The name 'modelItem' does not exist in the current context

Comment: The Column "Serial" is not present in the datatable, i need to append something like 1,2,3,4... (row count).

Comment: Changed the first line to - @foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i+1 })) - start counter from one

Answer (score 6):

```
@foreach (var item in Model ) 
{
    <tr>
          <td> @( ((Int32) 1) + @Model.IndexOf(item) ) </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 @{int index = 1;}
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @index
            </td>              
        </tr>
        index++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
    @{ 
        int sno = 0;
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @{ sno++; }
                @sno 
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{ int i = 1; }
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @i
        </td>
        @{ i++; }
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.studentName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.studentID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.studentID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.studentID })
        </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @(Model.ToList().IndexOf(item) + 1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.studentName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.studentID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.studentID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.studentID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Welcome and thanks for contributing! While your answer is correct, it's missing a little explanation on how/why/what you did to make things a bit clearer.